# config.xml: How to overwrite Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController.php save function

Tags: adminhtml, overrides, xml

I try the override the `protected function _saveInvoice($invoice)` contained in `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController.php` but I did not manage...

I Have :

```
<?php
require_once "Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController.php";
class Mine_Shipmentmodule_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController
{
    protected function _saveInvoice($invoice)
    { 
        Mage::log("totototo");
    }
}
?>
```

and my config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>  
        <Mine_shipmentmodule>  
            <version>0.0.1</version>  
        </Mine_shipmentmodule>  
    </modules>

    <frontend>
...
    </frontend>

  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <Mine_Shipmentmodule before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mine_Shipmentmodule_Adminhtml</Mine_Shipmentmodule>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>

    <global>
   ...
    </global>

</config>
```

EDIT : Mine_Shipmentmodule.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mine_Shipmentmodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Mine_Shipmentmodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way! I am not sure it is the best, but is works.

```
    <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <modules>
            <mine_shipmentmodule before="FireGento_Pdf_Adminhtml">Mine_Shipmentmodule_Adminhtml</mine_shipmentmodule>
          </modules>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
```

If it can help !

Answer (score 1):

require_once `"Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController.php";`   ***`is not right process to  include an overwrite  controller`***.

Instead of **calling overwrite controller class,you should include it path at proper way.**

InvoiceController.php should be called like this

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Adminhtml").DS."Sales".DS."Order".DS."InvoiceController.php";
```

**Instead of**

```
require_once "Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController.php";
```

**Thus magento auto loader easily understand it path**

Controller code is in below  and it should be located at *`app/code/community/Mine/Shipmentmodule/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order`*

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Adminhtml").DS."Sales".DS."Order".DS."InvoiceController.php";
class Mine_Shipmentmodule_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController
{
    /*public function newAction(){
    }*/
}
?>
```

**config.xml rewrite code should be**:

Mine_Shipmentmodule_Adminhtml

The *controller is override properly.* I have **`checked with newAction`** and it is properly working that **means _saveInvoice() should be override properly**,if any other **extensions are not override again**.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I made the change, but same result... my customized function is not called. The original is...

Comment: did you  have `Mine_Shipmentmodule.xml ` at app/etc/modules/

Comment: yes, i edited the post with it.

Comment: Maybe it's stupid question, but are you sure that _saveInvoice() function is executed? Try to override addCommentAction(), add comment in Invoice History and see what happens.

Comment: _saveInvoice exit at  that class and it several time function captureAction,voidAction

Comment: I add a Mage::log to the original function and I could check it was called... but not my module version of the function

Comment: Sorry Amit, but I do not manage to make it work. The goal is to modify the capture function which call the _save invoice using $this->_saveInvoice($invoice); Could you please add your the config.xml you have used? Thank you again

Comment: I think I found the problem : another module already extends InvoiceController to modify the print function. Can the controller be extended twice ?

Comment: yes. magento have feature to extend same controller twise.little  busy now..Will be reply after 3hrs

Comment: thank you very much. Disabling the other module make this one work. but I need both...

Comment: which one ,are you execute first ?

Comment: both my own module and firegento_pdf extend the class, but not the same functions : _saveInvoice for my module and printInvoice for firegento. When I comment in firegento config.xml the override, my module works. Therefore, firegento might be called after...

Comment: did you manage to find a solution ? thank you again for your help!